# if outer measure of $E$ is $\sup \{ m^*(K) : K \subset E \text{ with K compact} \}$ then $E$ is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded set such that $m^*(E) = \sup \{ m^*(K) : K \subset E \text{, with K compact} \}$. Show $E$ is measurable.

$m^*$ is Lebesgue outer measure.

Comment: What if $E$ is a non-measurable set that contains a set of infinite measure? Take a non-measurable subset of $[0,1]$, say $N$ and then let $E = N \cup [2,\infty)$. Then clearly $m^* E = \sup_n m^* [2,n]$, but $E$ is not measurable.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include that $E$ is bounded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An outline:

1. Build an increasing sequence of compact sets $K_n\subset K_{n+1}$ so that $m^*(K_n)\to m^*(E)$.
2. Recall that, since the $K_n$ are measurable, we have $m^*(E)=m^*(E\setminus \cup K_n)+m^*(\cup K_n)$ (this is Caratheodory's criterion).
3. Lebesgue measure is complete (meaning zero outer measure sets are measurable).

Obviously step 2 might fail to give enough info if $m^*(E)=\infty$, as was noted in the comments.